# Disabling a tinyMCE Editor using javascript

Tags: javascript, tinymce, disabled-control

I have a form that has a `tinyMCE` editor on its `textarea`.
I post form content using Ajax.
I need to disable editor and its `textarea` (disabling I mean and not removing it) while Ajax code is working.
How can do it?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by disabling the editor? do you want to disable editor actions?

Comment: @Thariama: I mean like when we disable a `button`; I want it be visible but grayed out and nonfunctional ; so I can disable it in this manner and process Ajax and re-enable it.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case you will need to apply the class `mceButtonDisabled` to the `a`-element of your button. Tinymce will then take care of the greying-out.